# Gradle sync not auto-resolve Android library project dependencies with @aar annotation

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, gradlew

I've created an Android library project found here: https://github.com/dbotha/Android-Photo-Picker

The photo-picker library project itself has several dependencies of it's own:

```
// library build.gradle
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

I've made this library project available on Maven Central so that it can be easily added to applications as a dependency:

```
// application build.gradle
dependencies {
    compile 'ly.kite:photo-picker:1.1.2@aar'
}
```

The problem though is that when I come to add it as a dependency to a new Android application project it crashes because it can't find the Picasso dependency from the library project:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.squareup.picasso.Picasso" on path`

It's only when I explicitly add this dependency to the applications build.gradle do things work.

My libraries POM file `dependencies` looks correct: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ly/kite/photo-picker/1.1.2/photo-picker-1.1.2.pom

So I'm curious if applications that include my photo-picker library as a dependency always need to explicitly add all the photo-picker library dependencies too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `@aar` notation.
It means that you want to download only the aar artifact, and no dependencies.
You can check this part of [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html):
Check the `1.4.1.2. Artifact only notation` section:

> An artifact only notation creates a module dependency which downloads only the artifact file with the specified extension. **Existing module descriptors are ignored**.

Using the `@aar` notation if you want to download the dependencies, you should add `transitive=true`.

I'd expect that omitting @aar it should work.

Comment: Perfect removing @aar did exactly what I wanted -- thank you very much!